# not importing from another class

Tags: java

Okay, I've got the following code:

```
package executive;

import animals.*;

public class MainFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        dog Robbie;
        Robbie = new dog();

        Robbie.lick();
        Robbie.jump();


    }

}
```

In the package animals I've got the class dog (Yes I know it's a really useless program):

```
package animals;

public class dog {

    void lick() {
        System.out.println("lick lick");
    }
    void jump() {
        System.out.println("Whihoooo");
    }
}
```

But if I'm running this code (eclipse) I get an error: 
"The method lick() from the type dog is not visible
The method jump() from the type dog is not visible"

The most people with this problem haven't made the class public, but I have. 
The code is working well at the moment I'm putting the dog-class in the same package.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the Java naming conventions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current visibility of both methods is [package-private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) (no explicit modifier) which means they can be accessed only from classes within the same package.
Since `MainFile` and `dog` are not in the same package, these methods cannot be accessed.
You will need to declare the 2 methods as public.

Comment: Great, just don't forget to accept one of the answers you got

Answer (score 2):

Default visiblity without any access modifier is invisible to the world.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

Because your methods `lick` and `jump` are package private i.e. the are only visible within package animal

to answer your question: make them either public methods or if package private is desirable move `MainFile` class into animal package

Comment: well then how do I make my package public

Comment: By adding the "pubilc" keyword in front of "void"?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the methods as `public`.

```
public void lick()
```

Taken from [this website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm)

> Default access modifier means we do not explicitly declare an access modifier for a class, field, method, etc. A variable or method declared without any access control modifier is available to any other class in the same package. The fields in an interface are implicitly public static final and the methods in an interface are by default public.

Where `access modifier` is the word `public`, `private` or `protected` before a variable or method declaration.

---

While I'm here, have a look at the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). These naming conventions are designed to make all code readable, and in a standard format.

Your first error is the naming of your `dog` class. The name should be `Dog` because all classes start with a capital letter.

Your second error is with your variable name `Robbie`. This should be `robbie` because all object references and variables should start with a lower case letter. If the variable has more than one word, it starts with a lower case letter, and all subsequent words start with an upper case value. For example `validVariableName`.

Answer (score 0):

the methods are mot visible because they are not public. Make them public and it should work
Because methods without access modifiers are not visible to other packages even when you import the package

```
package animals;

public class dog {

    public void lick() {
        System.out.println("lick lick");
    }
    public void jump() {
        System.out.println("Whihoooo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Java Access Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Methods need access modifiers as well as classes.

If you leave off the access modifier the default is called "package private" which means only classes in the same package can call the method.

If you want the methods to be available to call by classes in other packages you should change the access modifiers to `public`.